# Android: ListActivity with ListView start new intent and this intent don't have parent

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I've a ListActivity with a ListView, onItemClick i start an Intent,

Oncreate of this Intent i make a getParent but it's null. if i do this.isChild() it's false.

```
mPostList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent IntentDiscution = new Intent(parent.getContext(), EcrireMessage.class);
    ....
    IntentDiscution.putExtras(objetbunble);
    parentClass.startActivity(IntentDiscution); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only thing that can have a child [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is an [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html).

Take a look at this discussion thread for more details: http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/1ed4648486b6af64/

Answer (score 0):

You probably looking for

```
YourParentClassName.this
```

code

```
mPostList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent IntentDiscution = new Intent(YourParentClassName.this, EcrireMessage.class);
    ....
    IntentDiscution.putExtras(objetbunble);
    parentClass.startActivity(IntentDiscution); 
}
```

Comment: i've this error : "No enclosing instance of the type List is accessible in scope"

Comment: Post your entire file, as something else might be wrong there